# Symfony EasyAdminBundle custom view

Tags: php, symfony

I'm starting with [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle)  for Symfony.

For default usage it is perfect, but what if I wanna create custom view and use for it custom controller?

Let's say I have a task to load json file, display all his data and user then can edit data and save them.

Ok, I have my own custom controller, no big deal, data are loaded, I have custom view, data are there. I can click on link in left menu and see them. Ok. But I can't put together this view with EasyAdminBundle. To show view in a this nice theme. What I have to extend?

'@EasyAdmin/default/layout.html.twig'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want to extend the default layout you can extend EasyAdminBundle's layout.html.twig like this:

```
 {% extends '@EasyAdmin/default/layout.html.twig' %}
```

You can also check out the default templates e.g. for [lists](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/default/list.html.twig), but unfortunately the are a bit hard to read due to the high level of abstraction.

Comment: it's not functioning, I see only blank page

Comment: In that case make sure you are using the development-environment and have error_reporting set appropriately (e.g. to E_ALL) and display_errors enabled in your php.ini to check if there are any errors. This should give you an exception page instead of a blank page, that tells you what the problem is, e.g. "Unable to find template "EasyAdminBundle/default/layout.html.twig" (looked into: ...)". You can also check your application logs (by default in project_root/var/logs/dev) and your php logs (usually part of apache/nginx-logs in /var/log) for any errors and expand your question.

Comment: Och, nevermind, you are right so this is it:

{% extends '@EasyAdmin/default/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {{fileName}}
    <br />
    {{version}}
    <br />

    {% for key, value in translations %}
        <li>{{ key }} : {{ value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}